# How to Send Edit Text Inputs to a Specific String

Tags: android, string, input, textview, android-edittext

I would like to send edit text to a specific string, so that each time the user types something in to the edit text, whatever the user types is sent to that same string each time. Now the string represents whatever the user has typed into that specific edit text box. I would now use this string to display the string in a text view. Is this possible and how could you do this?

Basically I also want the text in the edit text to be identical to that of the text in the text view as well.

code examples of what I'm trying to do:

```
EditText AValue = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
AValue.setText( R.string.EditTextInput );

//What I want to do: Whatever User Types is always = String R.string.EditTextInput 
//User makes input equal a String when they press a button, which brings to new activity with text views
```

text view activity

```
private void populatescheduleList() {
        myschedule.add(new schedule_view("G Band", R.string.EditTextInput));
```

Comment: You want to set the text from an `EditText` to a `TextView` each time the text in the `EditText` changes?

Comment: yes, but it would be helpful if the text was devoted to a string so I could use it in other places.

Comment: Why do you need that? You can obtain the `String` at any time like this: `String text = editText.getText().toString()`.

Comment: I tried this before, but i was confused to if this was saved to a specific string and which string it was saved? I'm sorry if this is a noobish question?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? Could you please edit a code example into your question?

Comment: I have added the code examples, if you need more detail please ask and thank you for being so helpful

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but if you want the `String` from the `EditText` to be saved in `R.string.EditTextInput` than no that is not possible. `R.string.EditTextInput` belongs to the static resources. These are created when you compile your app into an apk and cannot be changed at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
       yourString = s.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `TextWatcher` to listen to text changes in an `EditText`. This `TextWatcher` subclass takes a `TextView` and each time the `String` in the `EditText` changes it sets the new text to the `TextView`.

```
public class EditTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    private final TextView target;

    private EditTextWatcher(TextView target) {
        this.target = target;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        this.target.setText(s);
    }
}
```

You would us it like this:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new EditTextWatcher(textView));
```

Of course you have to be careful with listeners like this. Don't forget to remove the `TextWatcher` later if you have to!